# You have attempted to use a rendering extension that is either not registered for this report

Tags: reporting-services, wonderware

i try to generate a reports automaticly, i use wonderware archestra. but i have this problem when i wante to generate and save a report:

Exception in GenerateReport: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: You have attempted to use a rendering extension that is either not registered for this report server or it is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: You have attempted to use a rendering extension that is either not registered for this report server or it is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportExecution2005Impl.InternalRender(String Format, String DeviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, Stream& Result, String& Extension, String& MimeType, String& Encoding, Warning[]& Warnings, String[]& StreamIds)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportExecution2005Impl.Render(String Format, String DeviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, Byte[]& Result, String& Extension, String& MimeType, String& Encoding, Warning[]& Warnings, String[]& StreamIds)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportExecutionService.Render(String Format, String DeviceInfo, Byte[]& Result, String& Extension, String& MimeType, String& Encoding, Warning[]& Warnings, String[]& StreamIds)

in my report i have parameters , 2 DateTime , 1 intger and 1 String 
( sorry for my bad english )
if someone can help me to result my problem , i'll be thanksful

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an obsolete question, but it has many views and maybe others that are looking for solution for similar issue would find my answer helpful. I've struggled with this error for a moment.

#### Introduction

`Rendering extensions` are used in report presentation. It is a component or module of a Report Server that transforms report data and layout information into a device-specific format.

SQL Server Reporting Services includes few rendering extensions:

- HTML
- Excel
- Word
- CSV
- Text
- XML
- Image
- PDF

To determine which rendering extensions are available, you can view the list of installed extensions in the RSReportServer.config file. In my case this file was under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER14\Reporting Services\ReportServer` and it had most of extensions installed.

[image]

#### Issue description & solution

In my case SSRS report generation worked. However on my client's machine it did not. We were generating report automatically to excel file using **`EXCELOPENXML`**. There was no entry with `EXCELOPENXML` in my client's config. I've managed to find out that this extension was new in SQL Server 2012, while my client used version 2008 R2 - **this was the reason** - like error says `attempted to use a rendering extension that is either not registered for this report server or it is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services`.

> EXCELOPENXML - The Reporting Services Excel rendering extension, new in SQL Server 2012, renders a report as an Excel document that is compatible with Microsoft Excel 2007-2010 as well as Microsoft Excel 2003 with the Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint installed. The format is Office Open XML and the file extension is XLSX.

**Solution for my case was to change report format from `EXCELOPENXML` to older rendered `Excel`.**